# Is it possible to store an object in a data structure (or even in another object) in Python?

Tags: python, object, data-structures

I think the title says everything about my question.
Is it possible?
I already tried with a list, singly linked list and even a double linked list and none of them worked.
I mean, they "worked" but when I tried to print the object inside, it showed the direction of the object.

Here's an output:

```
[<paquetes.Paquete object at 0x0000026AC70C0C88>]
```

My object is from "Paquete" class in "paquetes" python script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things at play here, and I am not entirely sure what you want to achieve.

#### 1. Representation

If you want to change how your object is printed, you can do that using the [`__repr__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) (which returns a string to be printed), like this:

```py
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.x} and {self.y}"
```

Your `__repr__()` method can return any string you like and that gives you some information about the object's data.  If you do not provide a `__repr__()` method of your own, Python just prints the object's memory address (which is what you are observing).

Instead of `__repr__()`, you could also use `__str__()`, of course.

#### 2. Objects and Memory Layout

In languages like C, a union structure actually *contains* the data of its fields.  If you have two bytes `12` and `34` (with binary representations `0000 0110` and `0001 0010`, respectively) and store them in a (packed) union, you end up having a 16-bit integer `0000 0110 0001 0010`.

In Python, however, this is never the case (unless you use some fancy extensions like *NumPy*, which does store data in that "native" format).  The problem is that objects in general have an unpredictable size (which can even change at any time).  Whereas in C you know that a byte will occupy exactly 8 bits, an integer in Python can go from 1 byte all the way up to several gigabytes.  Putting the objects' data one after the other is therefore quite impractical.  The solution is to store references, instead, because each reference has a fixed width of either 32 or 64 bit (depending on your system).

So, *technically*, Python only ever stores the reference (location in memory) of an object (the `0x0000 026A C70C 0C88`in your example) and never the actual data of an object.  But *logically*, we still say that a list, say, *contains* its elements.

If you really need to have a stream of data representing your objects, you might want to look at the [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to store an object in a data structure […] in Python?

In Python, *everything* is an object, so if it weren't possible to store objects in data structures, then *nothing whatsoever* could be stored in data structures. If it were only possible to store things that aren't objects, that would be pretty useless, since there *is nothing which isn't an object*.

Therefore, the answer is "Yes": Objects can be stored in data structures, otherwise Python would be completely and utterly useless.

> Is it possible to store an object in [another object] in Python?

In Python, *everything* is an object, so if it weren't possible to store objects in other objects, then *nothing whatsoever* could be stored in data structures (since everything is an object, data structures are also objects). If it weren't possible to store objects in objects, that would be pretty useless, since *nothing whatsoever* could be stored at all.

Therefore, the answer is "Yes": Objects can be stored in objects, otherwise Python would be completely and utterly useless.

Comment: By saying "object" I'm exactly talking about an instance of a class.

Comment: In Python, *everything* is an object, and thus everything is an instance of a class. Therefore, asking whether you can store objects in data structures is the same as asking whether you can store objects in objects (since data structures are objects), which is the same as asking whether you can store anything in anything (since there is nothing you can store and nothing you can store it in that isn't an object).